# How to format correctly and join lines on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a formatted HTML file

I want Join lines in Notepad ++
I use `ctrl + j`

### example:

[image: https://media.giphy.com/media/TersKT6fu4m0vdnI68/giphy.gif]

But now  https://media.giphy.com/media/hvG3Dk1DfRHvW4CiR8/giphy.gif

Lines should start with < h2 >, I don't know why it starts from an image file.
It could be something with breaking lines - `\n` but not sure.

this works

```
 "<h2>"

            "</h2>"
                "design/design.005.jpg"  
                Neat thick dreads, slightly messy dreads, skinny dreads… 



 "<h2>"
                A Wavy Messed up Side Part
            "</h2>"
                "design/design.006.jpg"  
                This hairstyle designed for men with soft curly hair. 




 "<h2>"
                Afro Blowout Styles
            "</h2>"
                "design/design.007.jpg"  
                Black guys usually have awesome, voluminous hair.  whole look.
```

This not working

```
 "<h2>"  
                High Seas Single Line
            "</h2>" 

                 "2-100/2-100.010.jpg"    
                Another cool single line tattoo, this one takes a subject that is usually done up with detail and breaks it down into the simplicity of its parts. 
 "<h2>"  
                Tipping the Scales
            "</h2>" 

                 "2-100/2-100.011.jpg"    
                It actually took me a minute to figure out what this tattoo was. At first I thought 
 "<h2>"  
                Fibonacci Sequence
            "</h2>" 

                The Fibonacci sequence, as I understand it, takes two
```

Comment: Please make this a complete question by including the text from your Notepad++ file directly in the question.  Do not paste image links.

Comment: added code lines

Comment: Why do I see quotation marks in your HTML tags `<h2>` and `</h2>`?

Comment: same results with quotation marks or not, i use quotation marks for extra editing in another program

Comment: Choose View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters and check your line breaks.